# Subtraction of a list of numbers in racket

Tags: list, racket, subtraction

I'm trying to subract a list of numbers using recurssion in racket. The function goes like:

```
(define (sub lst)
 (cond [(empty? lst) 0]
       [ else (- (first lst) (sub (rest lst)))]))
```

This doesn't seem to be correct as racket performs subtraction from left to right. I.e eg:

`(- 1 2 3 4 6)` is suppose to be -14. But when i do it in the same way as giving in the list through recurssion, like `(list 1 2 3 4 6)` it gives the result as 4. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

So your function does this:

```
(sub '(1 2 3))      ; ==
(- 1 (- 2 (- 3 0))) ; ==
(- 1 (- 2 3))       ; ==
(- 1 -1)            ; ==
; ==> 2
```

What you function needs to do is this:

```
(- (- 1 2) 3)  ; ==> -4
```

There is also special cases for 0 and 1 argument:

```
(sub '())  ; ==> 0  (identity of - is 0)
(sub '(1)) ; ==> -1 (- identity 1)
```

Comment: @user3607109 Yes. The operation needs to happen from left to right instead of right to left like you made it.